# Trying to Compare Instance of Class Directly to a String

Tags: c#, string, operator-overloading

How can I make a class like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private string m_value;
    public string Value { get { return m_value; } set { m_value = value; } }
    public Foo()
    {
        m_value = "";
    }
}
```

be directly comparable with a string without needing to access it's `.Value` property so that I can do:

```cs
Foo m_foo = new Foo();
m_foo = "someString";

if(m_foo == "someString")
{
    Console.Writeline("It Worked!");
}
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: I believe that there is a way to define how your class is compared, but I'd suggest just using the `.Value` property anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the == operator (the compiler also requires you overload '!=', 'Equals', and 'GetHashCode')

```
public class Foo
{
  private string m_value;
  public string Value { get { return m_value; } set { m_value = value; } }
  public Foo()
  {
    m_value = "";
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    return this.Value == obj.ToString();
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return Value.GetHashCode();
  }

  public static bool operator ==(Foo a, string b)
  {
    return a.Value == b;
  }

  public static bool operator !=(Foo a, string b)
  {
    return a.Value != b;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if all of that effort is worth it though, when you could just write:

```
if(m_foo.Value == "someString")
```

Comment: Great, I'll try that... the reason was so that I can have something that acts and is used very much like a string as a property in some other class, but can be filtered out by a `Type` comparison instead of using a `Regex.IsMatch()` on the `PropertyInfo.Name` which is more prone to my human error and typos.  This other class also has String properties, so I think this will be a better way to filter which ones I want at any given time.